# TextView making slight movements

Tags: android, textview

I have 2 TextViews.  The first is `centred` and the second is aligned against the rightmost edge of the parent.

When I update the text in the `Second TextView` it makes the `first TextView` move slightly to the left then come back to its original position in the centre.

i have no idea what is happening

This is the relevant part of my .xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MC_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could please just update the xml with all of its content? It seems something is missing, at least in the first TextView. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think probably **android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"**, instead of **android:layout_centerInParent="true"** would fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the size of your outer RelativeLayout depends on the size of its children.
Since you have `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` inside your first TextView, when the size of the RelativeLayout changes so does its center.

Comment: The width never changes though, it is set to match_parent

Comment: Yes but the layout pass happens and during layout the view gets measured multiple time. Try to set the size of the RelativeLayout to a fixed value. Just to check if this is the problem